# Jest/Enzyme with styled components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I can't for the life of me get Jest/Enzyme to play nicely with styled components.

I have a component I am mounting that filters out a list of 5 of the most recent shipments.

```
  it("should have five shipments", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<LastFiveShipments shipments={dummyProps.shipments} />);
    wrapper.debug();
    const styledList = wrapper.find("styled.ul");
    expect(styledList).exists().to.equal(true);;
  })
```

```
const LastFiveShipments = ({shipments}) => {
  return (
    <StyledList>
      <h5>Last Five Shipments:</h5>
      {
          shipments.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.cargo_units[0].created_at) - new Date(b.cargo_units[0].created_at))
          .filter((shipment, index) => index < 5)
          .map((shipment, index) => <li key={index}>{shipment.reference}</li> )
      }
    </StyledList>
  )
}

const StyledList = styled.ul`
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #14374e;
  margin: 1em 0;

  & li {
    text-align: center;
  }
`;
```

`styled.ul` is the displayName and `find` is having no luck selecting it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also rename your styled component to make it easier to read. For example

```
const StyledList = styled.ul`
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #14374e;
  margin: 1em 0;

  & li {
    text-align: center;
  }
`;

StyledList.displayName = 'ul';
```

test.js

```
expect(wrapper.find('ul')).toHaveLength(1)
```

In that way, you don't need to import your styled component

Answer (score 6):

You can import the component you're searching for, in this case `StyledList`, and use it instead of `"styled.ul"`

```
import StyledList from ''

wrapper.find(StyledList)
```

Comment: It's a styled ul inside of a component.

Comment: You can export the styled component so it can be imported and used to `.find` in your tests

Answer (score 1):

@Donovan beat me to it.

Anyway, I was able to replicate the same problem, however, there are two workarounds:

1. Instead of using `shallow`, you can `mount` the component and then assert: `expect(wrapper.find("StyledComponent > ul")).toHaveLength(1);`.
2. Instead of `mount`ing the component, you can `import StyledList from 'path/to/styledList';` and then assert: `expect(wrapper.find(StyledList)).toHaveLength(1)`

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Styled Component]